# Как запустить yii2 advanced на сервере apache?

Tags: php, yii2, hosting, apache2.4

Пытаюсь запустить yii2 advanced проект на сервере apache 2.4.10 
Проект устанавливал через composer.phar, он установился, выполнил php init(все прошло без ошибок), по идее я должен увидеть сайт перейдя по адресу /mysite.com/frontend/web однако выдает ошибку 
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server. 
Если подставляю .htaccess файлы (как на локальном сервере, где все работает хорошо), выдает ошибку сервера, не смог выполнить запрос. Я, по моему, пробовал все что гуглится.
Как быть? 
Что делать?

P.S. 
использую тестовый хостинг beget,
apache 2.4.10,
php 5.6.40,
composer 1.8.6

Comment: Убедитесь что у директорий **runtime** и **web/assets** установлены права доступа 777.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно надо сделать

```
php init
```

и выбрать тип окружения - продакшен или дев.

Далее идем по адресам

```
http://вашдомен/frontend/web/
http://вашдомен/backend/web/
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте после php init также выполнить две команды:

```
composer install
composer update
```

Если не поможет - обновите права доступа к файлам:

```
chmod -R 777 /path_to_project
```

...и затем снова php init, composer install, composer update

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь! Сделал по этой иструкции https://bender-blog.ru/en/post/1/  только приложение указал advanced